# How can i change namenode?

Tags: hadoop

I configured my hadoop system in 5 machines. and I will get new one soon and this machine
has more resources such as memory. So I want to change configuration that the new one is
namenode. How can I change it without preserving my data in HDFS? 
Thank you

Comment: You mean preserving your data or without preserving?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Shut down** your cluster.
2. **Copy over the contents** of the dfs.name.dir directories from the previous NameNode and ensure that they have the **right permissions** on your new machine.
3. Make sure that the new **NameNode** is set to point to those directories (**check the dfs.name.dir setting in hdfs-site.xml** -- in fact, you should copy the entire set of config files from the old NameNode to the new machine, but do a sanity check to make sure that any directories they point to exist on the new machine).
4. Now change the **slave nodes and clients to point to the new NameNode** (fs.default.name in core-site.xml on each machine including the NameNode itself) and you should be able to bring your cluster up again.